# python sms store using class

Tags: python-3.x, function, class

Im trying to get a basic sms program running within a python file. 
The idea is that the program ask you a question of do you want to send or read an sms. each sms would have a from_number,message_body and read/unread tag. SO the idea is you start by seding an sms then you enter your source number and text body. it stores it in a list. then you can recall that massage later and when you read it the unread flag needs to change to read.

the parts i think is the biggest problem is understanding how to specify the class instance and using the functions inside the class when taking user input and passing it on to the program.

the SMS1 code is an attempt to generate a manual instance with its attributes.

maybe i have this whole structure wrong.
any assistance would be much appreciated.

```
#An SMS Simulation

SMSStore = []
#start of the class
class SMSMessage:


    def __init__(self,messageText,fromNumber):
        global SMSStore
        self.messageText = messageText
        self.fromNumber = fromNumber
        #self.originnumber = originnumber
        #self.hasBeenRead = False

    def MarkAsRead(self):
        self.hasBeenRead = bool(True)

    def add_sms(self,smses):
        for number in range(smses):
            soure_number = int(input("please enter source number..."))
            message_body = str(input("please enter message body..."))
            new_message = (soure_number,message_body)
            SMSStore.append(new_message)
            return print(SMSStore)

    def get_count(self):
        return print(SMSMessage.count())

    def get_message(self):
        return print(len(SMSStore))

    def get_unread_messages(self):  #still need to figure this out with a read or unread tag
        pass

    def remove_sms(self):
        sms_to_del = int(input("which sms number do you want to delete: "))
        del SMSStore[sms_to_del]
sms1 = SMSMessage("hello","123")


print(sms1.fromNumber)
print(sms1)


userchoice = None

while userchoice != "quit":
    userchoice = input("what would you like to do - read/send/quit?")
    if userchoice == "read":
        SMSStore.get_count()
        #place your logic here
    elif userchoice == "send":
        smses = int(input("number of smses to be added"))
        SMSMessage.add_sms(smses)
        #place your logic here
        print(SMSStore)
    elif userchoice == "quit":
        print ("goodbye")
    else:
        print ("oops - incorrect input")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my example, check it:

```
class Messenger:

    sms_store = [{'title': 'test', 'text': 'Some text here', 'readed': False}]

    def __init__(self):
        self.greeting()
        self.prompt()


    def greeting(self, *arg, **kw):
        print('Hello there!')
        print('In your inbox {} messeges, ({} is new)'.format(
            len(self.sms_store), len(list(filter(bool, [not x.get('readed') for x in self.sms_store])))))

    def prompt(self):
        while True:
            command, *args =  input("\nWhat would you like to do?\n> ").split()
            if command == 'quit':
                break
            elif hasattr(self, command):
                getattr(self, command)(*args)
            else:
                print('>>> Wrong command! <<<')

    def list(self, *arg, **kw):
        print('Messeges:')
        for n, sms in enumerate(self.sms_store):
            print('Num:', n, 'Readed:', sms.get('readed'), 'Title:', sms.get('title'))

    def get(self, sms_num, *arg, **kw):
        if not sms_num or int(sms_num) >= len(self.sms_store):
            print('>>> Wrong msg Number! <<<')
        else:
            sms = self.sms_store[int(sms_num)]
            print(sms.get('title'))
            print(sms.get('text'))
            self.mark_readed(int(sms_num))

    def mark_readed(self, sms_num, *arg, **kw):
        self.sms_store[sms_num]['readed'] = True

    def add_sms(self, title, *arg, **kw):

        self.sms_store.append({'title': title, 'text': ' '.join(arg), 'readed': False})
        print('Msg added!')

    def remove_sms(self, sms_num, *arg, **kw):
        if not sms_num or int(sms_num) >= len(self.sms_store):
            print('>>> Wrong msg Number! <<<')
        else:
            self.sms_store.pop(int(sms_num))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    m = Messenger()
```

Output:

```
~ > $ python3 test.py 
Hello there!
In your inbox 1 messeges, (1 is new)

What would you like to do?
> list
Messeges:
Num: 0 Readed: False Title: test

What would you like to do?
> add_sms New_sms Some text is here!
Msg added!

What would you like to do?
> list
Messeges:
Num: 0 Readed: False Title: test
Num: 1 Readed: False Title: New_sms

What would you like to do?
> get 1
New_sms
Some text is here!

What would you like to do?
> list
Messeges:
Num: 0 Readed: False Title: test
Num: 1 Readed: True Title: New_sms

What would you like to do?
> remove_sms 0

What would you like to do?
> list
Messeges:
Num: 0 Readed: True Title: New_sms

What would you like to do?
> close
>>> Wrong command! <<<

What would you like to do?
> quit
~ > $
```